# How get name of Toplevel window of another Toplevel?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

```
import tkinter as tk


r = tk.Tk()
r.title("root")
r.geometry("200x200")
f =tk.Frame(r)
f.pack()

top1 = tk.Toplevel(f)
top1.title("A")
#some widgets inside top2

top2 = tk.Toplevel(top1)
top2.title("B")  

print(top1.winfo_toplevel(), top1.winfo_children())

r.mainloop()
```

I only want to get the toplevel of `top1` and nothing else i.e `.!frame.!toplevel.!toplevel`

`winfo_toplevel()` returns `.!frame.!toplevel`

`winfo_children()` returns `.!frame.!toplevel.!toplevel`, ... all children

Comment: so `top1.winfo_children()[0]`?

Comment: You cannot get `.!frame.!toplevel.!toplevel` no matter how because `top1` is the `Toplevel` and its parent is a `Frame` not `Toplevel`.  You can get the root window (`.`) using `top1.master.winfo_toplevel()`.

Comment: @HenryYik but it will not necessarily be at index 0 there could be widget before and after it.

Comment: @acw1668 `top1.master.winfo_toplevel()` why does this give root and why does `top1.winfo_toplevel()` give `.!frame.!toplevel ` i am confused

Comment: `widget.winfo_toplevel()` will return itself if `widget` is a `Toplevel`, otherwise return the `Toplevel` containing `widget`.  So `top1.winfo_toplevel()` will return itself, i.e. `.!frame.!toplevel`.  `top1.master` is `f`, so `top1.master.winfo_toplevel()` is the same as `f.winfo_toplevel()` which returns the root window.

Comment: Note that `top2.winfo_toplevel()` will give the result you want: `.!frame.!toplevel.!toplevel`.

Comment: @acw1668 ok i got it thank you, btw Is there any way to get a specific child of a widget that will also do the job

Comment: @Bind I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but what I *think* you're asking is how to get `top2` given only `top1`.

There's no direct way to do that. You can get all of the children of `top1` and then return any children that are `Toplevel` widgets. If you know that `top1` only has a single child that is a `Toplevel`, you can then return the first child that is a `Toplevel`.

```
def get_toplevel(w):
    for child in w.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_class() == "Toplevel":
            return child
    raise Exception("No toplevel window was found")
```